# Error while uploading file on amazon s3 storage: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, hadoop, cloud

While uploading a file on Amazon s3, I am getting this error message.For this project I am using hadoop for processing file and then uploading the output files on cloud.Jars used for the same are:
aws-java-sdk1.11.80, hadoop 2.7.1, httpClient 4.4.4 and other required jars.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:87)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:51)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:39)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:319)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:303)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:164)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:563)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:543)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:525)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:497)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:479)
```

Comment: can you show us the code you use to upload the file?

Comment: It's a dependency probleṃ, check what libraries you're using at runtime and try to find out why they're not the same as during compile-time.